# Make android UI pixel perfect from a xxhdpi device psd

Tags: android, android-layout

I know that 1px in psd means 1dp in mdpi so the matrix is like whatever pixel I am getting in mdpi divide it by 3 to get dp to be set on xxhdpi to be pixel perfect. Is this the correct approach ? . Secondly how do I support different screens(mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi) from this psd . Should I have to make different layouts for different screen resolutions(That would be difficult ask as then I have to control 4 screens instead of one) or define dimensions in res folder for different screen resolutions (mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi and xxhdpi) and check whether its looking fine in different screens . I want my screens to be pixel perfect for any resolution . I know there is no correct or wrong answer but what should be my approach. Further I would also really appreciate if there are some tools that can help me to fasten the process of development compatible with linux and should be free.

Comment: You better scale **DOWN**. I.e.: make a 3x sized graphichs for xxhdpi, Then android will divide it by the required scale factor. Scaling down will average the pixels, blending them. Scaling up will enlarge the pixels (pixellation) - very ugly.

Comment: Thanks Der, I think you are only talking about images.. but what about margins from left , right, bottom or top and the text sizes....would I need to make diffrent layouts for that?

Comment: Simply use dimension resources.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension